# calculate db data in fastreport

Tags: oracle11g, delphi-7, fastreport

In fast report 4, I have a memo with a database value inside. let's assume it is memo1 and inside is [frxDBDataset2."AWAL"]. then I have another memo --memo2 and inside is [frxDBDataset1."DEBET"]. for short it'll be:

```
memo1:=[frxDBDataset2."AWAL"]
memo2:=[frxDBDataset1."DEBET"]
```

Now, I wanted to calculate memo1 and sum of memo2, then show in in memo3. for short it'll be :

```
[frxDBDataset2."AWAL"]+sum of [frxDBDataset1."DEBET"]
```

how and where do I do this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have two different datasets as a Master/Detail?Are trying to put this in a Master Footer band?

Comment: @MarkElder yes, 2 different datasets. however I solved it yesterday. the [,(, and < are a bit confusing to me when I wrote code, but now it's solved. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
[<frxDBDataset2."AWAL"> + SUM(<frxDBDataset1."DEBET">, MasterData1)]
```

Comment: I solved it. the [,(,and < is a bit confusing which came first and all, but it's solved. thanks!